# Search text using strstr function in C

Tags: c, search, text

I'm making a search program, but it does not output the sentences for my input.
It shows nothing in the end. Just the 'search for:' in the line 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char tracks[][80] = {
"I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
"Newark, Newark - a wonderful town",
"Dancing with a Dork",
"From here to maternity",
"The girl from Iwo Jima",
};

void find_track(char search_for[])
{
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for))
printf("Track %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
}
}

int main()
{
char search_for[80];
printf("Search for: ");
fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
find_track(search_for);
return 0;
}
```

Using Visual Studio 2010 with C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
```

if you give input `heart` after you are pressing return key

`fgets()`  reads newline into `search_for`

```
    Now search_for=="heart\n";
```

remove `\n` at the end of search_for

```
   if(search_for[strlen(search_for)-1]=='\n')
      search_for[strlen(search_for)-1]='\0';

   find_track(search_for);
```

Comment: Another question : How to lowercase input characters using tolower functions ?

Comment: `tolower()` Converts c to its lowercase equivalent if c is an uppercase letter and has a lowercase equivalent. If no such conversion is possible, the value returned is c unchanged.See examples which explains [tolower()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_tolower.htm) and [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to replace:

```
fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
```

with

```
fscanf(stdin, "%s", search_for);
```

With this method, be careful not to enter more than 79 characters in your search though.

Comment: I would *not* recommend to replace `fgets` by `fscanf`, exactly because of the buffer overflow problem. In production code, this could be a potential security problem.

Comment: Also those functions behave differently. `fscanf` reads only until any white space.